# Doubt regarding Conversation between Allah (s.h), Angles and Adam(a.s)

Tags: quran, tafseer

I have a doubt regarding a certain conversation between allah (s.h)  angles and Adam (a.s).

> From 2:31 to 2:33

Allah taught all the names to Adam. Then asked angles to name them. Angles failed.

> They (angels) said: "Glory be to You, we have no knowledge except what
>   You have taught us. Verily"

Then Allah asked Adam to do the same. Adam succeed.

I think it is to show how humans are superior. But if Allah didn't teach Adam the names, he shouldn't be able to answer, right?
Or if Allah taught Angles the names before, Angles should be able to answer right?

My question is like this
I have two friends, One day i bought a unknown object and shared it's name with one friend. Then i asked other one to name it. Obviously he won't be able to name it. But the other one should be able to name it, since i told him the name before.

So above situation is not fair if you are comparing 2 persons intelligence, right?

I'm not sure if i misunderstood the statements. Please correct me if i'm wrong on anything above.

Comment: Why should these verses be about fairness or knowledge? Why not about the fact that everybody has his strengths and weaknesses.

Comment: @Medi1Saif Does that mean Angels don't have the ability to learn while humans?

Comment: That was just a line of thought not anything reliable. I mean angels have been created to obey and worship. Humans have different God given abilities.